# How can Legacy Boot be enabled on a 2019 ThinkPad?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, thinkpad, csm

I have a 2019 [ThinkPad X390](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x390?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=X390%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)) with Windows 10 and want to install Ubuntu. I have always used Legacy Boot previously, not UEFI, and want to see how to have that option. In the UEFI-BIOS, I can see that the option to change `UEFI/Legacy Boot` from `UEFI Only` to `Legacy Only' is not selectable and beside it is written the text

```
Unselectable for Kernel DMA Protection
```

How can the option to change this be enabled?

Comment: When you press F10 or whatever to choose to boot from the Live USB, you will see two USB options. One will say boot from USB. The other will say boot from UEFI USB or some such thing. Choose wisely. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955?r=SearchResults#1134955

Comment: Time to embrace a UEFI install! It’s not that difficult. The link above should help. You might be able to scrap Windows and do a legacy install of Ubuntu but you cannot dual boot without UEFI.

Comment: Ach, maybe it is time, I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing in order to be at least *able* to do a legacy boot. I'm not wanting Windows at all btw.

Answer (score 2):

I had same Problem on my Lenovo t490. I just went under the tab Security and the Virtualization, there was the option Kernel DMA Protection, and I switched it off. Now I'm able to switch legacy mode on.