# Operating System that boots depends on boot mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows.

When I try to run Ubuntu on Grub, it works fine. When I try to boot windows from Grub, it tries for a few seconds and then returns to grub.
[Grub Page IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ORl.jpg)

In Bios, if I set boot priority to legacy first, I am able to get the Grub screen where windows is unable to boot but Ubuntu can. However, if I set Boot Priority to UEIF first, Windows boots normally without showing the Grub screen and giving me the option to boot into Ubuntu.

[BIOS IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZw3I.jpg)

Here are some things I tried:

1) Updated Grub

2) Ran boot repair, ran into this error:
[boot-repair error IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3PCV.jpg)

3) As shown in the first image, I added Windows (UEIF) too grub, but, when I choose that option, it outputs "invalid signature. press any key to continue"

Comment: See the pictures in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) to make sure the Ubuntu Live USB starts in UEFI mode. Otherwise it will not install in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you installed Ubuntu in BIOS (legacy) and Windows in UEFI mode. Those aren't compatible. I'd advise you back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu making sure that you boot the Ubuntu flash drive in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did install Ubuntu in BIOS (legacy) mode. I think when I was installing ubuntu originally, it was having difficulty installing in UEFI mode. I think I am going to try again.

Comment: Good luck with the reinstall! If your computer doesn't find your flash drive in UEFI mode try a different USB port. That's worked for me in the past.

Comment: Yeah the computer didn't boot with the flash drive but I was able to get it going through the power menu. The reinstall worked perfectly thanks for the help! I ran into so many problems trying to dual boot it's not even funny, but I am glad it is over.

Comment: Glad it works! Enjoy! :)