# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and now Windows doesn't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I installed Ubuntu along with Windows 10. the problem that I'm facing is that I cannot boot back to my Windows after I installed Ubuntu. I tried to run boot-repair  but it said:

> LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB).

What should I do?

[Here is the log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8VXMRNrVvP/plain/)

Thank you

Comment: I have found [this solved issue of the same problem on linux mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322292), see if it helps. Edit your question with updates if you are stuck somewhere in the process and need help.

Comment: GRUB will boot both Ubuntu and Windows 10 as lon as both are either UEFI or both BIOS mode. To install Ubuntu in BIOS mode boot the installer USB in BIOS mode.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) for how to know if you booted the Ubuntu Live USB in UEFI mode or in LEGACY mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always get the same problem when I install Ubuntu to my nvme ssd hard drive alongside Windows 10.

I think the problem is related to uefi or mbr or efi or legacy which I know nothing about

But after searching for hours I always fix this problem with this method:

**NOTE**: this method not the easiest or the best, but at least it works

1. Burn Windows to USB
2. Plug the USB into your computer
3. Start the computer and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or whatever key you use to access the boot menu)
4. Select the USB in the boot menu
5. Choose language and press next
6. Select **Repair your computer**
7. Select **Advanced**
8. Select **Command prompt**
9. Enter the following commands:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmb
   bootrec /fixboot
   ```

   **Note:** it's ok if the above step returned access denied or something like that

   ```
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
   ```

Then reboot and repeat the steps from number 3 to 7

Now instead of opening the command prompt choose **Fix startup problems**

After that you are done.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks!

Comment: why advanced option does not appear in my usb windows installation ?