# Installing Ubuntu for Dual Boot with Windows Leaves Space Unallocated and Boot Loader Unchanged

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have made multiple attempts to install Ubuntu with dual boot on my nvme drive. Currently, I have shrunk my C: partition by 64 GB in order to allow space for Ubuntu.

[image]

I am using a flashdrive as installation medium for Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.1. I am able to boot into the installation medium and run the installation process in its entirety, finally receiving the message "Installation Completed". I then reboot, and find that not only has my boot loader been left as the windows boot loader, but that the 64 gb where Ubuntu was to be installed is still marked unallocated. I have tried both the "Install alongside windows" and "Something else" modes (I set the unallocated space to be partitioned as ext4 and mounted as /), and both yield the same result.

I still have secure boot enabled, but this hasn't been a problem as far as I can tell. I also have completely disabled BitLocker and unencrypted my entire drive, but this has made no difference.

Comment: You may have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode instead of UEFI mode. Windows Disk Management does not understand the partition format used by Ubuntu. So, you it looks like "unallocated" to Windows. [See this answer for how to boot from the Ubuntu Live USB in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955). Install Ubuntu again (in UEFI mode) replacing the existing Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for the input, I will make sure to try that out when I have a chance. On the topic of that partition being "unallocated", I checked with the Live USB on GParted and it showed that space as EXT4 but 0 bytes were used.

Comment: @user68186 I didn't see anything about disk encryption in the installation process, so I'm assuming not. I did forget to mention that several installations crashed due to a bug with installation of 3rd party drivers with nvidia cards, so I may be remembering one of those times.