# Why i am getting issues when i boot ububtu from usb drive?

Tags: kubuntu, windows-10, unetbootin

[there’s the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ayMa.jpg) i have an hp intel core i7 64gb, i am tryin to use ubuntu by booting it from the usb drive, i download it on the usb by unetbootin.But when booting it keeps showing the loading screen.

Comment: For me Rufus (instead of unetbootin) always works like a charm. Try and give it a go and create your USB once more.

Comment: Your USB drive may have bad sectors. Your ISO download may be corrupt. You have to check and let us know.

Comment: how can i check if the ISO download is corrupt?

Comment: See all the answers to the question [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd).

Comment: Another thing to consider is how you are trying to boot from the Live USB. Live USB can be booted in UEFI mode or Legacy (also known as CSM, or BIOS) mode. Some USBs can be booted in either mode, some can be booted in only one mode. If you want to dual boot with Windows, and Windows was installed in UEFI mode (most current ones are) then you have to boot your Ubuntu Live USB in the UEFI mode. Otherwise when you install Ubuntu into your internal drive it will install in Legacy mode, and that will be a problem.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) for more.

Comment: i didn’t download ubuntu thru ISO, i download it by the distributor and Unetbootin downloaded the zip file then it’s extracted it.