# Problem with mounting File Systems from External Drives

Tags: usb, mount, fstab

some time ago I set up my Ubuntu to mount external drives always on the same mountpoint. To do that, I mounted according to the UUID, e.g. from my fstab:

```
UUID=b949cee0-9e93-44c1-b3eb-1857cf5c1167 /media/b949cee0-9e93-44c1-b3eb-1857cf5c1167 ext4 nofail,auto,noatime,rw,user 0 0

UUID=17fbaabc-84e1-49a5-aebf-e14dfd1f5502 /media/17fbaabc-84e1-49a5-aebf-e14dfd1f5502 ext4 nofail,auto,noatime,rw,user 0 0
```

I did so when I used a non-powered (i.e. it doesn't have a power plug), 4-port USB hub: I connected the drives to the Hub, and the Hub is connected to the computer.

I thought that the UUID is ummutable, and that my drives would be mounted at the same mountpoint all the time (which in my case for some reason I named with the UUID as well).

However it happens that when the drives are attached to the USB hub, they are mounted. When they are NOT attached to the hub but are connected directly to the computer, they are  not detected at all. Not only the are not mounted, but also when doing lsblk, they don't show up.

How can this be possible? Any hints?

EDIT:

Ubuntu Version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Here is the output of lsusb:

```
No Drive Attached:

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

One Drive Attached (no hub attached)

nardo@myserver:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

One Drive attached through USB Hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1348720/edit) and add the following information: version of Ubuntu, and output of the command `lsusb` when the drives are not connected , connected directly, connected via hub. Copy the output from the terminal and paste directly into the question. Then format the output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Could that be a powered hub, and could it be that directly connecting them does not provide enough power?

Comment: @vanadium it's not a powered hub

Comment: @user68186 I edited the question as you suggested :-)

Comment: I see in the `lsusb` output that the drive is only recognized when attached via the bub. This is strange. I don't have a solution.

Comment: @user68186 I am starting to think it has to do with some weird stuff after an update. I also can't mount SMBs because "Unable to find suitable address" (although it worked well until a short time ago...)

Comment: Can you take a look at the [pictures in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) and then boot from the Ubuntu installation USB again to see if you are booting the USB in in UEFI or BIOS mode? If you see the UEFI mode screen then try to boot the USB in BIOS mode. An update never makes new partitions.