# Problem installing 20.04 from USB

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, usb

Machine: Lenova T510 that had Ubuntu 18.04 on a different HHD, Ubuntu worked w/o problems until HHD failed.

HHD: SP SSD SATA III

I made a bootable USB drive using the same USB that I loaded 18.04 with.  At first I used the Startup Disk Creator on the failing HHD (18.04) using the Tutorial [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview), but that didn't work, so I remade it using Rufus on my Win10 laptop following the tutorial [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).  I have the new SP SATA III HHD in the Lenova now.  The laptop will boot from the USB, but I do not see the Welcome and Install screen that's in the Tutorial, I see a purple screen with, at the bottom, a rectangular box that looks like a USB drive, an "Equal" sign to the right and then a circle with a stick figure in it:

[image]

If I hit any key it goes to screen with a list of Try Ubuntu (normal and safe graphics), Install Ubuntu (normal and safe graphics), Test Memory, and Boot from first hard drive

[image]

[image]

The mouse/track is not working at this point, but I can go up/down through the list.  I've tried each, but it just reboots.  If I do nothing it sits on that purple scree for 15 seconds then reboots.

UPDATE: I formatted the USB drive and rebuilt the bootable USB, downloaded the ISO again.  Same results.  But, I did try the "F" keys at the bottom of the screen

F4 Gives me this:

[image: F4 Gives me this]

F5 Gives me this

[image: F5]

F6 Gives me this

[image: F6]

I did notice that after hitting F6 there is a line just above the F keys that says Boot Options and then "file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity initrd=casper/initrd quiet splash ---".  I do not have anything in the cdrom drive. Why would the creation of the USB use the cdrom to install the OS?

UPDATE: I made a DVD install disk, booted with it, but get the same screens and same outcome.  The laptop does not have UEFI for a boot option.

Comment: Do you see the words `GNU GRUB` at the very top of the screen?  It sounds like you are seeing the initial GRUB menu, in which case you should only need to press the `enter` key to continue booting.  If it doesn't boot, there is probably another error message that is flashing by on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your note.  I put some pics above.  The only text I see before the first purple screen is "SYSLINUX 6.04 EDD 6.04-pre1", then "Loading bootlogo...", then Initializing gfx code..."  I had to capture a video since it was so quick.

Comment: It looks like you are booting the USB in the BIOS mode. This should be fine if you use the MBR type partition table in your new HDD. If you have used GPT type partition table, then you may want to boot the USB in the UEFI mode. See the answer to [Installation problems with GRUB, can only install by reinstalling Windows in legacy mode but need to keep in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg) for more.

Comment: That might be the problem.  The SSD is brand new and I haven't done anything to it.  The BIOS recognizes it, but it looks like there isn't any partitioning.  Thanks

Comment: It looks like this laptop does not do UEFI mode.

Comment: You mention 2 tutorials "here" that you followed in your question but fail to link to what you followed. Please [edit] your post to include this information that you felt was important enough to mention. Thank you for helping us help you!