# What options should I choose with my specs to install Ubuntu with Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Sorry, I'm new to Linux. I am trying to make Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10. I have MBR SSD, legacy BIOS, and I get EFI partition not found error during Ubuntu installation. I made 60 GB of free space on my disk to install ubuntu on it.

I looked at many articles about installing Ubuntu alongside with Windows, but none of them had the same situation as I do, so I was worried, that it wouldn't work properly for me.

So what partitioning options should I choose while installing ubuntu? What partition should I choose for Device for boot loader installation? Which option should I choose while booting?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the pictures in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg) You get different screens if you boot your Ubuntu installation USB in UEFI or CMS (Legacy) mode. Sometimes when you select to boot from a USB, you see two USB to choose from: One will have the word UEFI in it. **Don't choose that one!** :-)

Comment: A legacy Windows will be on an MSDOS partitioned disk, which is limited to only four primary partitions.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes  Install Ubuntu in the same mode, legacy, and all its partitions may be logicals within the extended partition.  Or consider backing up, and since your machine apparently is UEFI capable, change disk partitioning to GPT, reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: Rather than backing up and re-installing Windows, as @ubfan1 suggests, using Microsoft's [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) tool may be easier, if switching to EFI-mode booting is desired. That said, installing Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, as creeprawman's answer details, is likely the easier and safer approach, at least in the short term.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Ubuntu installer is booted in legacy mode. Here is how you can do that. Open boot menu of BIOS. Pressing a specific key opens boot menu of BIOS. There you will find 2 USB drives plugged in. While one flash drive is actually plugged in, both options are for different boot methods. For example, "Sandisk Curzer Blade" <-- is for a legacy boot and "Sandisk Curzer Blade (EFI)" <-- is for an UEFI Boot. Next, you must create 2 partitions. One is for Ubuntu itself and one is for Swap Space, then format the Ubuntu partition as ext4 and format the swap space as swap fs. Next, select the Ubuntu partition, then in boot loader location you can specify the root of the hard disk. (Keep in mind this will remove the Windows Boot Manager, but you will still able to boot into windows as it will be automatically added to GRUB menu.) Hope this helps.