# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an old laptop. It's a Dell Inspiron n 7110. I can try Ubuntu from the usb stick without issues. When I install it everything goes ok, it finishes and tells me to restart the system. After I restart it tells me to remove the USB stick and press enter. After that the system kind of restart and then it only shows `Operation System not found`.

The HD is a 250GB crucial SSD that had two partitions with win 10. When installing I selected the Option to remove everything and install Ubuntu, but I keep getting the same results.

Finally I ran the computer diagnostic and nothing failed.

---

For the comments of @user68186, here is the information of the HD
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu 22.04? If yes, please edit the title (Ubuntu Core 22 is a different OS).

Comment: I updated the title. It is in fact 22.04 LTS (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Also as a PS, right now I'm using the try Ubuntu option from the USB stick using Firefox. So it works perfectly in the laptop

Comment: @user68186 OLD Bios, the laptop is from 2012. How can I find if the internal drive is initialized as MBR or GPT?

Comment: @user68186 I edited the question and included an image with the disk data

Comment: did you select to boot to Ubuntu in your BIOS?

Comment: In the BIOS I select the HD that in theory has Ubuntu installed, but the same happens. Like I said in the question, in theory ubuntu is actually installed, I remove the USB stick and then I get the message. The boot order is USB and then the HD, since there is no USB in the system, the BIOS defaults to the HD and I get the message Operation System not found. But if I change the order to HD first and then USB or other device, the same happens. The result is the same regardless of the boot order

Comment: @user68186 Where exactly I can see that? In the boot menu of the USB stick I don't see it
https://www.linuxtechi.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Try-Install-Ubuntu-22-04.png

Comment: When want to boot your computer from the USB you may be pressing F2, F10 or some other key to see the options to boot from USB. When you see those choices, do you see two choices for USB? If so, what are those choices? Does one of those say "UEFI something USB" or "USB something UEFI"?  If so, that is the option you should choose.

Comment: Alternately, Boot from the USB with "Try Ubuntu" option and open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and enter the command `ls /sys/firmware/efi`. If you get a bunch of names of files and folders then you have booted in UEFI mode. If you get `cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory` Then you have booted in BIOS mode.

Comment: Let me know the results of the `ls /sys/firmware/efi` test, and update your question with it. Thanks.

Comment: Try the solutions in [this question and all its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955)