# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 alone causes no boot device found but works when dual booting with windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have been trying to install only Ubuntu 22.04 on my whole hard drive, installation goes smoothly but it won't boot up - no boot device found error and install an operating system on your hard drive shows up.

After researching, I tried reinstalling GRUB  through Live USB but to no avail.

My laptop is HP EliteBook 8460p and it doesn't have UEFI support (experimental one doesn't recognizes USB or HDD for boot menu)

I used Rufus to burn the USB so it's in legacy mode already.

But I noticed that when I install Windows 10 and then install Ubuntu by dual boot option, it works like charm.
And I only want to have Ubuntu as my OS on entire hard drive.

Is it that Ubuntu 22.04 only supports UEFI systems? Or is there something else that I am missing?

Pardon me for my bad English.

Comment: Try the solutions in [this question and all its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955)

Comment: Some early UEFI systems which yours may be only wanted to boot Windows. And back then one work around was to just name the Ubuntu UEFI entry as "Windows Boot Manager". But if BIOS boot, it should just be a case of making sure UEFI/BIOS is set to boot in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, which ever it is called. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: boot-repair gives this error:    The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.

Comment: The problem with my laptop is that there is no UEFI boot option available for HDD or USB.